# JavaFX: Unable to include JavaFX runtime in classpath

Tags: java, maven, javafx-2

I am developing a JavaFX application, working on Java 1.7(build 1.7.0_25-b17). Hence I assumed that javafx runtime was included in the java runtime. The project has some dependencies and those are defined in the pom.xml file.

[image: Classpath]

The problem I have at hand is that the javafx runtime(jfxrt.jar) does not seem included in the class path as shown above. Due to this, my application shows compile errors pointing to javafx classes. Is there anything I am missing.

The maven dependencies are show below:

[image: Maven dependencies]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the javafx runtime separately to the pom as below and it worked:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.min.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Now this picks up the javafx runtime from the java version installed rather than picking up an older version. This eliminates any problems with using old versions.

Answer (score 1):

From [*What is JavaFX?*](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm#A1095238):

> JavaFX 2.2 and later releases are fully integrated with the Java SE 7 Runtime Environment (JRE) and the Java Development Kit (JDK).

This means you should be able to just use the `javafx.*` packages without adding any library besides the JDK. It seems that Eclipse and Maven are being stupid in your case. (The JavaFX library and a bunch of others are in `$JDK_HOME/jre/lib/*`, Eclipse only seems to add what's in `$JDK_HOME/lib`. IntelliJ IDEA does the right thing here.)

Comment: I understand this, but I am unable to include any javafx packages in my application as shown in my question. Also, the javafx runtime is not included in the classpath(also shown above). interestingly, if I add the following dependency to the pom file, the project is able to include the javafx packages.   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-runtime</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @user1539057 I think that's a holdover from when JavaFX shipped with the JDK, but wasn't included on the default classpath. If adding the dependency manually works for you, I'd just do that, using `<scope>provided</scope>` maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the response [millimoose](http://stackoverflow.com/users/41655/millimoose). The problem there is that I cannot change the version from 2.2.0 to any higher version(Sorry, this should be a different question though).

Comment: Whenver I do, it says, "Missing artifact com.oracle:javafx-runtime:jar:2.2.X" on whatever value of 'X' I give other than '0'.

Comment: @user1539057 A fix for that would be installing the appropriate JAR into your local repository. That said, the `<scope>system</scope>` solution is better, I just couldn't get that to work for some reason so I didn't bring it up.

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX in Java7 is not on any classpath - you need to adjust your project classpath or use a tool like e(fx)clipse which manages that for you.

In Java8 it is on the extension classpath!